# How to change child class of an object

Tags: django, django-models

I have a base model which is inherited by two other models. How can I change a Tender object to an OfferRequest object while keeping ProcurementRow relation intact? My purpose is to convert a Tender into an OfferRequest on demand.

```
class Procurement(models.Model):
    pass

class ProcurementRow(models.Model)
    procurement = models.ForeignKey(Procurement)

class Tender(Procurement):
    pass

class OfferRequest(Procurement):
    pass
```

Comment: When you say "change a Tender object to an OfferRequest object" what do you mean? What do you mean convert Tender into an OfferRequest "on demand?"

Comment: When I convert a Tender object to an OfferRequest object, a new OfferRequest object must be created and all data from Procurement object should be transferred to new object. By on demand I mean, this should be a programmatic solution and an user should be able to achieve this with a click of a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with raw sql queries.

```
def convert_procurement(request, procurement_id):
    procurement = get_object_or_404(Procurement, id=procurement_id).parent()
    from django.db import connection
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        if isinstance(procurement, Tender):
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO procurement_offerrequest(procurement_ptr_id) VALUES (%s)", [procurement.id])
            cursor.execute("DELETE FROM procurement_tender WHERE procurement_ptr_id=(%s)", [procurement.id])
            return redirect('procurement:create_offer_request', procurement.id)
        elif isinstance(procurement, OfferRequest):
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO procurement_tender(procurement_ptr_id) VALUES (%s)", [procurement.id])
            cursor.execute("DELETE FROM procurement_offerrequest WHERE procurement_ptr_id=(%s)", [procurement.id])

            return redirect('procurement:create_tender', procurement.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the fields of `Procurement` and then use getattr/setattr to copy the fields. I'd also recommend making a hard relationship via a `ForeignKeyField` between the two so you can keep track of how things occurred.

```
class Tender(Procurement):
    pass

class OfferRequest(Procurement):
    tender = models.ForeignKey(Tender)

    @classmethod
    def from_tender(cls, tender):
        instance = cls()
        instance.tender = tender
        for field in Procurement._meta.fields:
            if field.auto_created:
                continue
            setattr(
                instance,
                field.name,
                getattr(tender, field.name, None)
            )
        instance.save()
        return instance

tender = Tender.objects.first()
offer_request = OfferRequest.from_tender(tender)
```

Comment: I can see instance is well being created but it's not saving to database. Is django pulling some strings behind our backs for the sake of integrity?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent using raw SQL, this can be done with the following :

```
tender_id = 123
tender_object = Tender.objects.get(id=object_id)

# Delete the record in the tender table, keeping the record in the procurement table :
tender_object.delete(keep_parents=True)

# Create the record in the offerrequest table :
offerrequest_object = OfferRequest(procurement_ptr_id=tender_id)
offerrequest_object.save_base(raw=True)
```